# ABI issue in standard pancakeswap fork

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, solidity

I am trying to create a fork of pancakeswap/goosedefi.  The project works when I check it out from github and start using yarn start.

As soon as I change the contract addresses, symbol, and ABI to match my new project, I get the following error:

"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced"

The ABI matches the ABI generated by BscScan for the contract address.

Has anyone successfully forked PancakeSwap and gotten past this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to fork It too and i've encountered the same error multiple time. You should check which function throw this error becouse the original cause can be a wrong farms or pools configuration. For example i've the same error throwed by useFetchBalances hooks and navigating through the stack i've seen that useCakeBnb/useCakeBusd cause the problem too, so i've configured pools and now It works fine.
I Hope that this can be helpfull for you